# Как сделать впритык кнопка + поле

Tags: html, css

Не могу разобраться, как сделать кросс браузерно впритык кнопка + поле. Вот вариант. http://jsfiddle.net/EeDxD/
Если смотреть в фаерфоксе - все ок. В опере или хроме - кнопка на пиксель съезжает вниз. Если поправить bottom  - будет съезжать в фаерфоксе.

Comment: Зачем у вас bottom: -1px ? из-за этого и съезжает. Ещё можно vertical-align: middle обоим добавить. Думаю ещё и line-height в разных браузерах - разное значение по дефолту принимает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через @-moz-document url-prefix() сойдет ?

http://jsfiddle.net/EeDxD/1/

Comment: пойдет. Спасибо за способ.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это вам поможет:
Делайте один div в него вставьте кнопку и поле, чтобы высота кнопки чуть заползала на див, а ему самому overflow: hidden; не забудьте их поставить впритык, например float: left; или с помощью margin